# Get a property of a javascript object using another property

Tags: javascript, web

Here's a list of objects for example:

```
const products = [
  {
  name: "Cherry",
  price: 10,
  quantity: 0,
  productId: 1,
  image: "../images/cherry.jpg"
},
{
  name: "Orange",
  price: 15,
  quantity: 0,
  productId: 2,
  image: "../images/orange.jpg"
},
{
  name: "Strawberry",
  price: 3,
  quantity: 0,
  productId: 3,
  image: "../images/strawberry.jpg"
}
];
```

I want to get the other properties of an object from the list using its productId. I'm a beginner in JavaScript so I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `products.find(function(item) { return item.productId==productId})`

Answer (score 0):

```
products.find((product) => product.productId === pid) // where pid is the id of the product you want to find
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your description is that you want to find out the product property of a specific items  from the list for that you can use

==**ES6**==

products.filter( (item) => { return item.productId==productId})

==**Vanila js**==

products.filter(function(item) { return item.productId==productId})

Comment: It's not a good practice to use filter here because it returns an array while the desired output is an object. Use find instead